# Trying To Correct retail price display

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working with a code that seems to be displaying incorrectly. In my slider I have mulitple products that are displayed. When the script runs it should grab the retail price from each of the products.

Currently, it is only grabbing the retail price of the first product. Some of the sliders will display the retail price without the strike through as well.

Any suggestions could help, and I appreciate it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ajax_load = " ";

var loadMagaziner = "/spotlite-deals/";    
$("#SpotliteDeals .slider-block .ProductList").html(ajax_load).load(loadMagaziner + " .ProductList li", function(){
     var $window = jQuery(window),
        flexslider = { vars:{} };

        // tiny helper function to add breakpoints
        function getGridSize() {
        return (window.innerWidth < 601) ? 1:
           (window.innerWidth < 900) ? 1 : 1;
        }

        // check grid size on resize event
        $window.resize(function() {
            var gridSize = getGridSize();

            flexslider.vars.minItems = gridSize;
            flexslider.vars.maxItems = gridSize;
        });
    jQuery('#SpotliteDeals .BlockContent .slider-block').flexslider({
            animation: "slide",
            //selector: 'ul.ProductList > li',
            slideshow: false,
            itemWidth: 285,

            controlNav: true,
            minItems: 1, // use function to pull in initial value
            maxItems: 1 // use function to pull in initial value 
        });

        var rprice = jQuery(this).find('.p-price .RetailPriceValue').html();
               var sprice = jQuery(this).find('.p-price .SalePrice').html();

             if(rprice && sprice ){
                var newrp = rprice.replace('$','');
                var newsp = sprice.replace('$','');
                var newds = Math.round(((newrp-newsp)/newrp)*100);

                jQuery(this).find('.p-price .RetailPriceValue').append().html('Price: <strike>' + rprice + '</strike> (' + newds + '% off)' );
                jQuery(this).find('.deal-tag').css('display','block');
             } else {
                jQuery(this).find('.deal-tag').css('opacity','0');

             }
}); 

</script>
```

Comment: I'm confused by your helper function, I can't see how it returns anything but `1`? (Although, admittedly, this is probably entirely off-topic).

Comment: please read this first : [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)